# Why the Cauchy Stress Tensor & the Stress-Energy-Momentum Tensor have the same SI units?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, dimensional-analysis, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

Shouldn't adding time as a dimension changes the Stress-Energy-Momentum Tensor's units? What math operation(s) (if any) would transform the 3D Cauchy Tensor into the 4D Energy Momentum Tensor of GR?

Comment: We add $ct$ as the extra dimension which has the same units as $x$. So no units are changed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Prahar! So what do you do exactly to transform one into the other?